# Inserts on to linked server taking long time

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 servers (server1 sql server 2008r2 standard, server2 sql server 2014 standard).
I want to insert some data from server1 to server2 using linked server and i have created thye query like below.

```
Insert into Linkedservername.dbname.dbo.tablename (col1, col2 )
    select col1, col2 
    from dbo.server1tablename
```

only 20000 records but taking arround 45 minutes.
If I pull data from server2 then it is taking arround 20 seconds.

Can any one suggest how i can push data with minimum time.

Comment: Do it vice versa. Pull data from Linked server and insert it locally. Also, if this is a repetitive process, better use BCP or SSIS as Linked Servers are relatively slow.

Comment: Check this out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46289/which-one-is-more-efficient-select-from-linked-server-or-insert-into-linked-ser

Comment: The opposite way is doing absolutely perfect. When i pull data from remote server this is doing very well, the process is very slow when we use push data from local server.

Comment: Pull the data always, it is quick and effective. Your destination server in 2014 as u said, using merge procedure is effective way of incremental loading

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.